# Issue saving JPG images from binary data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having issues with a function that creates JPG images given a binary string. The program saves two images in quick succession, the first is ~300kb and the second is a cropped version of the same image, around ~30kb

The first (larger) image always saves correctly, however the second image sometimes (Maybe 1 in 4) gets cut off half way, with the lower part of the image being flat grey. Opening the image in notepad++ , it looks like the data just abruptly stops being written

The function that creates the images:

```
def writeImage(imageData, decoded, imageNumber, config):
    if imageNumber == 1:
        imageSavePath = image1name
    elif imageNumber == 2:
        imageSavePath = image2name
    print(imageSavePath)
    file = open(imageSavePath, 'w+b')
    file.write(imageData)
    file.close
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFVvu.jpg

This is an example of how the images turn out, the amount that is cut off varies image to image

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your file isn't being flushed before closing. This should happen automatically when you close it. Your code appears to be missing the () for the close call, e.g. it should be

```
file.close()
```

The more pythonic way of handling the file object though is to use a `with` statement as a context manager. So the code would look like this

```
def writeImage(imageData, decoded, imageNumber, config):
    if imageNumber == 1:
        imageSavePath = image1name
    elif imageNumber == 2:
        imageSavePath = image2name

    print(imageSavePath)

    with open(imageSavePath, 'w+b') as file:
        file.write(imageData)
```

The file will automatically be closed when you are done with executing the statements nested in the `with`. This ensures you don't forget to close it and leak the file descriptor.